# Mapbox with Leaflet Markercluster in Blazor server app

Tags: blazor, mapbox-gl-js, leaflet.markercluster

I try this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-markercluster/) in my Blazor server application, but it throws this error:

```
leaflet.markercluster.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
at leaflet.markercluster.js:6
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read property 'mapbox' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mapbox' of undefined
```

Source:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
var map = L.mapbox.map(mapId)
        .setView([19.053534, 47.489706], 12)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you import all required cdn's?

Comment: I think so, but I have maden it in Leaflet with Mapbox layer. Thank you for your answer.